# Wordpress slider that allows image, headline, text, and button?

Tags: plugins, jquery, slideshow

I'm looking for a slider for Wordpress that will allow me to create a really clean-looking site—the kind of site where you land, you see text and images, and you don't even know you're looking at a slider until the text and images slide off and new ones slide in.

Kind of like this:
http://www.apple.com/iphone/

Or this:
http://www.dolbeau.ca/

I want this slider to allow me to:

- insert headlines as text (not as images)
- insert subheadlines as text
- include call-to-action hyperlinked buttons on each slide
- have all of these things overlap on top of the image, as they do on the dolbeau.ca site

Does anyone know of such a slider? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Meta Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/), the demos look nice.

Comment: You can also check out the [Gutenslider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenslider/) plugin. It lets you create nice wordpress sliders easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is David Caplan, the web developer at Dolbeau. I don't know how much web design experience you have but we basically just use the plain old carousel slider from Twitter Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) with some extra javascript thrown in. The key is the CSS that allows the images to be full screen and centered, even when the browser width is smaller.

I appreciate you comparing our site to Apple's :) Unfortunately, I don't know of a Wordpress plugin that exists for this kind of thing.